# Flattening nested loops / decreasing complexity - complementary pairs counting algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, loops, nested, complexity-theory

I was recently trying to solve some task in Python and I have found the solution that seems to have the complexity of *O(n log n)*, but I believe it is very inefficient for some inputs (such as first parameter being `0` and `pairs` being very long list of zeros).

It has also three levels of `for` loops. I believe it can be optimized, but at the moment I cannot optimize it more, I am probably just missing something obvious ;)

So, basically, the problem is as follows:

> Given list of integers (`values`), the function needs to return the number of indexes' pairs that meet the following criteria:
>
> - lets assume single index pair is a tuple like `(index1, index2)`,
> - then `values[index1] == complementary_diff - values[index2]` is true,
>
> **Example**:
>   If given a list like `[1, 3, -4, 0, -3, 5]` as `values` and `1` as `complementary_diff`, the function should return `4` (which is the length of the following list of indexes' pairs: `[(0, 3), (2, 5), (3, 0), (5, 2)]`).

This is what I have so far, it should work perfectly most of the time, but - as I said - in some cases it could run very slowly, despite the approximation of its complexity *O(n log n)* (it looks like pessimistic complexity is *O(n^2)*).

```py
def complementary_pairs_number (complementary_diff, values):
    value_key = {} # dictionary storing indexes indexed by values
    for index, item in enumerate(values):
        try:
            value_key[item].append(index)
        except (KeyError,): # the item has not been found in value_key's keys
            value_key[item] = [index]
    key_pairs = set() # key pairs are unique by nature
    for pos_value in value_key: # iterate through keys of value_key dictionary
        sym_value = complementary_diff - pos_value
        if sym_value in value_key: # checks if the symmetric value has been found
            for i1 in value_key[pos_value]: # iterate through pos_values' indexes
                for i2 in value_key[sym_value]: # as above, through sym_values
                    # add indexes' pairs or ignore if already added to the set
                    key_pairs.add((i1, i2))
                    key_pairs.add((i2, i1))
    return len(key_pairs)
```

For the given example it behaves like that:

```
>>> complementary_pairs_number(1, [1, 3, -4, 0, -3, 5])
4
```

If you see how the code could be "flattened" or "simplified", please let me know.

I am not sure if just checking for `complementary_diff == 0` etc. is the best approach - if you think it is, please let me know.

**EDIT:** I have corrected the example (thanks, unutbu!).

Comment: If something is not clear enough or if you have some questions, please ask them - maybe I could improve my question :)

Comment: I think the `key_pairs` in your example is `set([(3, 0), (0, 3), (5, 2), (2, 5)])` (note the 5, not 4). Yes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this improves the complexity to `O(n)`:

- `value_key.setdefault(item,[]).append(index)` is faster than using
  the `try..except` blocks. It is also faster than using a `collections.defaultdict(list)`. (I tested this with ipython %timeit.)
- The original code visits every solution twice. For each `pos_value`
  in `value_key`, there is a unique `sym_value` associated with
  `pos_value`. There are solutions when `sym_value` is also in
  `value_key`. But when we iterate over the keys in `value_key`,
  `pos_value` is eventually assigned to the value of `sym_value`, which
  make the code repeat the calculation it has already done.  So you can
  cut the work in half if you can stop `pos_value` from equaling the
  old `sym_value`. I implemented that with a `seen = set()` to keep
  track of seen `sym_value`s.
- The code only cares about `len(key_pairs)`, not the `key_pairs` themselves. So instead of keeping track of the pairs (with a
  `set`), we can simply keep track of the count (with `num_pairs`). So we can replace the two inner for-loops with

  ```
  num_pairs += 2*len(value_key[pos_value])*len(value_key[sym_value])
  ```

  or half that in the "unique diagonal" case, `pos_value == sym_value`.

---

```
def complementary_pairs_number(complementary_diff, values):
    value_key = {} # dictionary storing indexes indexed by values
    for index, item in enumerate(values):
        value_key.setdefault(item,[]).append(index)
    # print(value_key)
    num_pairs = 0
    seen = set()
    for pos_value in value_key: 
        if pos_value in seen: continue
        sym_value = complementary_diff - pos_value
        seen.add(sym_value)
        if sym_value in value_key: 
            # print(pos_value, sym_value, value_key[pos_value],value_key[sym_value])
            n = len(value_key[pos_value])*len(value_key[sym_value])
            if pos_value == sym_value:
                num_pairs += n
            else:
                num_pairs += 2*n
    return num_pairs
```

Comment: I believe it may be a bullseye :) It seems to return correct values at least for `complementary_diff=0` and `values=[0,0,0]` (see this code, you can use it eg. for tests: http://ideone.com/8bZ2x). I did not think about len*len :)

Comment: I cannot see anything wrong within your code :) I am going to accept it unless someone else will give better solution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ok, thank you for your outstanding solution! You got rid of the nested loops and found a way to simplify the code. My problem was that I was unnecessarily storing key_pairs and then had to use two `for` loops just to generate them instead of just calculating number of combinations on the basis of lengths. I regret I cannot give you more than one upvote, because this answer deserves more :)

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look into functional programming idioms, such as reduce, etc.

Often times, nested array logic can be simplified by using functions like reduce, map, reject, etc.

For an example (in javascript) check out underscore js. I'm not terribly smart at Python, so I don't know which libraries they have available.

Comment: Thanks, you may be right, but eg. `map()` does not solve the problem, as it still does the loop. It is even suggested to use list comprehensions / generator expressions in some cases. But `reduce()` may be useful somehow. Thanks again.

Comment: I may be missing something obvious, maybe this indeed could be solved easily by applying some theory from Algebra, but I cannot see it now, it was so long ago and if you have any tips, anything that can point me to the right direction, I would be grateful! :)

Comment: Well, by "Algebra" I mean "the process of reducing complexity using known rules"

#notenoughsleep #notenoughcoffee

Comment: Ok, I follow. I still hope I am missing some known rules. #meetoonotenoughcoffee

Answer (score 0):

I think (some or all of) these would help, but I'm not sure how I would prove it yet.

1) Take values and reduce it to a distinct set of values, recording the count of each element (O(n))

2) Sort the resulting array.
(n log n)

3) If you can allocate lots of memory, I guess you might be able to populate a sparse array with the values - so if the range of values is -100 : +100, allocate an array of [201] and any value that exists in the reduced set pops a one at the value index in the large sparse array.

4) Any value that you want to check if it meets your condition now has to look at the index in the sparse array according to the x - y relationship and see if a value exists there.

5) as unutbu pointed out, it's trivially symmetric, so if {a,b} is a pair, so is {b,a}.

Comment: Thanks, you may be pointing me in the right direction. Except that I believe when `a==b` (so index `a` points to the same element index `b` points to), then it should be counted only once (I mean element can be a pair with itself, but should not be treated as being a pair with itself twice).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can improve this by separating out the algebra part from the search and using smarter data structures.

1. Go through the list and subtract from the complementary diff for each item in the list.

   ```
   resultlist[index] = complementary_diff - originallist[index]
   ```

   You can use either a map or a simple loop. -> Takes of *O(n)* time.
2. See if the number in the resulting list exists in the original list.

   - Here, with a naive list, you would actually get *O(n^2)*, because you can end up searching for the whole original list per item in the resulting list.
   - However, there are smarter ways to organize your data than this. If you have the original list **sorted**, your search time reduces to *O(nlogn + nlogn) = O(nlogn)*, *nlogn* for the sort, and *nlogn* for the binary search per element.
   - If you wanted to be even smarter you can make your list in to a **dictionary(or hash table)** and then this step becomes *O(n + n) = O(n)*, *n* to build the dictionary and *1* * *n* to search each element in the dictionary. (*EDIT: * Since you cannot assume uniqueness of each value in the original list. You might want to keep count of how many times each value appears in the original list.)

So with this now you get *O(n)* total runtime.

Using your example:

```
1, [1, 3, -4, 0, -3, 5],
```

1. Generate the result list:

   ```
   >>> resultlist
   [0, -2, 5, 1, 4, -4].
   ```
2. Now we search:

   - Flatten out the original list into a dictionary. I chose to use the original list's index as the value as that seems like a side data you're interested in.

     ```
     >>> original_table
     {(1,0), (3,1), (-4,2), (0,3), (-3,4), (5,5)}
     ```
   - For each element in the result list, search in the hash table and make the tuple:

     ```
     (resultlist_index, original_table[resultlist[resultlist_index]])
     ```

     This should look like the example solution you had.
3. Now you just find the length of the resulting list of tuples.

Now here's the code:

```
example_diff = 1
example_values = [1, 3, -4, 0, -3, 5]
example2_diff = 1
example2_values = [1, 0, 1]

def complementary_pairs_number(complementary_diff, values):
    """
        Given an integer complement and a list of values count how many pairs
        of complementary pairs there are in the list.
    """
    print "Input:", complementary_diff, values
    # Step 1. Result list
    resultlist = [complementary_diff - value for value in values]
    print "Result List:", resultlist

    # Step 2. Flatten into dictionary
    original_table = {}
    for original_index in xrange(len(values)):
        if values[original_index] in original_table:
            original_table[values[original_index]].append(original_index)
        else:
            original_table[values[original_index]] = [original_index]
    print "Flattened dictionary:", original_table

    # Step 2.5 Search through dictionary and count up the resulting pairs.
    pair_count = 0
    for resultlist_index in xrange(len(resultlist)):
        if resultlist[resultlist_index] in original_table:
            pair_count += len(original_table[resultlist[resultlist_index]])
    print "Complementary Pair Count:", pair_count

    # (Optional) Step 2.5 Search through dictionary and create complementary pairs. Adds O(n^2) complexity.
    pairs = []
    for resultlist_index in xrange(len(resultlist)):
        if resultlist[resultlist_index] in original_table:
            pairs += [(resultlist_index, original_index) for original_index in
                original_table[resultlist[resultlist_index]]]
    print "Complementary Pair Indices:", pairs

    # Step 3
    return pair_count

if __name__ == "__main__":
    complementary_pairs_number(example_diff, example_values)
    complementary_pairs_number(example2_diff, example2_values)
```

Output:

```
$ python complementary.py
Input: 1 [1, 3, -4, 0, -3, 5]
Result List: [0, -2, 5, 1, 4, -4]
Flattened dictionary: {0: 3, 1: 0, 3: 1, 5: 5, -4: 2, -3: 4}
Complementary Pair Indices: [(0, 3), (2, 5), (3, 0), (5, 2)]
Input: 1 [1, 0, 1]
Result List: [0, 1, 0]
Flattened dictionary: {0: [1], 1: [0, 2]}
Complementary Pair Count: 4
Complementary Pair Indices: [(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 1)]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would be happy to see it coded, because I think there are places this logic may fail :) When it comes to your code: 1) I am using a hash table (`value_key`), 2) your `original_table` seems to be a set, 3) I do not need indexes, if it simplifies anything, 4) I am not sure what is flattening of the original list into dictionary for (could you explain it?). Anyway thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Yeah sure. I've added the code to the original answer. Regarding your questions 2) original_table is indeed a hash table(or dictionary) The squiggly brackets({}) indicate a dictionary in python. 4) The flattening of the original list into dictionary is what brings about the time improvement as explained in the last bullet of step 2. In short, dictionaries are much faster to search through then a list. Can you tell me where you think the logic might fail?

Comment: I believe that it fails eg. if you have two equal values within the input (`values` list). Eg. for the `1` and `[1, 0, 1]` arguments the function should return `4` (being the length of `[(0,1), (1,2), (1,0), (2,1)]`), but your function returns `3` (being the length of `[(0,1), (1,2), (2,1)]`). It just was not designed for the same value being placed at different indexes within the input. Two levels of `for` loops in my code were result of the fact the values within the input list may not be unique, so assuming they are unique would help me simplify my script a lot :) Anyway, thanks a lot :)

Comment: Ah okay. I see. In that case not caring about the actual pairs help a lot since you can just count them at the end. I'll reflect the change in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Modified the solution provided by @unutbu:

The problem can be reduced to comparing these 2 dictionaries:

1. values
2. pre-computed dictionary for (complementary_diff - values[i])

   ```
   def complementary_pairs_number(complementary_diff, values):
       value_key = {} # dictionary storing indexes indexed by values
       for index, item in enumerate(values):
           value_key.setdefault(item,[]).append(index)

       answer_key = {} # dictionary storing indexes indexed by (complementary_diff - values)
       for index, item in enumerate(values):
           answer_key.setdefault((complementary_diff-item),[]).append(index)

       num_pairs = 0
       print(value_key)
       print(answer_key)
       for pos_value in value_key: 
           if pos_value in answer_key: 
               num_pairs+=len(value_key[pos_value])*len(answer_key[pos_value])
       return num_pairs
   ```